# MVVM: Communication

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am working on a large MVVM application. I am using the MVVM light toolkit for this. The application is like a web browser with back and forward buttons. The main view is an user control. I laid the back and forward buttons in the main view user control. The main view in turn has user controls. The user controls change when the back and forward buttons are clicked. The main ViewModel keeps track of the current user control and loads the next one depending on the button click.

All these user controls are loaded depending on the selection(ID) made on the first step. Lets say, the main view is a search screen and we select a customer. The next screens would be Address, Billing, Requests, etc. These screens does not share any data. But the data is for the same customer.

So, is it a good practice, to store the customer ID in the main view? If I do this, I should have a UserControl_Loaded event bound to a command, where I would then request for Address and Billing Info.

Or I can move the buttons(back and forward buttons) to each user control instead of the main view, Pass the customer ID with the message which would load the next view.

Which is better?

Comment: To decouple things, consider using the MVVM Light `Messenger` to publish `CustomerSelected` messages (which can contain an Id), rather than using commands. Your other controls can then subscribe to this message.

Comment: My intial thought on this was, if the back and forward buttons are in the Main view, depending on the source(Current view), I need to send a message to the view models. I wanted to avoid that(sending a message in from the main view depending on the current view). So I was thinking of the User_Control Loaded event.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid sending a message?

Comment: I think, if I send message depending on the Current view and button click, essentially, I am sending the same message content(Customer ID)  over and over again.    Like, first there will be a message to the Address Screen from search screen with customer ID. Billing and Requests would also be registered to listen to that message. But at that point since they are not Instantiated yet, they won't respond. Now from Address, I need to send Customer selected message, which account has subscribed to listen to, with billing.

Comment: Now when Billing sends message, account also gets a message even though the customer did not change. I feel that I am doing something wrong here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way I've done this sort of thing in the past is to implement a class that encapsulates the data context for the operation.  All of the pages will be populated with (and update) properties of this class.  The main view model creates an instance of this class and a collection of the page view models, providing each with the data context.  It also handles navigation from page to page, implementing `CurrentPage`, `NavigateForwardCommand`, and `NavigateBackwardCommand` properties.

If the user backs up to page 1 and changes the customer ID, the data context is repopulated with the information appropriate to the new customer.  Since all of the pages are looking at the same data context object, all of the subsequent pages will display the right information.

You'll need to implement property-change notification in the data context object, and handle `PropertyChanged` in the pages.  When the `CustomerID` property changes in the data context object, the page view models will need to refresh properties that appear in their respective views.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add a few bits.... Each view, as well as the main view should have a data context representative of the kind of operation it is performing.  If customer selection is happening in main view, its data context should have a SelectedCustomerId property. But ultimately, main view will have to inform its children view of these changes somehow and one way is to give each child view a reference to the main view's data context from which they can determine current customer ID.

Comment: Hi, I am confused here. Sorry, if I am asking basic questions. But in MVVM light there is a View model Locator. We create an instance of the view model in that class. I tried to create a class that has all the view models and tried to Instantiate a view model. But it didnot work

Comment: I think you're going to need to investigate what's actually happening when you try to instantiate this object, and describe what, specifically, isn't working as you expect.